# LightGBM predicts negative values

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, lightgbm

My **LightGBM regressor** model returns negative values.

For **XGBoost** there is **objective='count:poisson'** hyperparameter in order to prevent returning negative predicitons.

Is there any chance to do this ?

Github issue => https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/5629

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LightGBM also facilitates an `objective` parameter which can be set to `'poisson'`. Follow [this link](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#objective) for more information.

An example for [`LGBMRegressor`](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMRegressor.html#) (scikit-learn API):

```py
from lightgbm import LGBMRegressor


regressor = LGBMRegressor(objective='poisson')
```

Answer (score 1):

LightGBM also supports poisson regression. For example, consider the following Python code.

```py
import lightgbm as lgb
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot

# random Poisson-distributed target and one informative feature
y = np.random.poisson(lam=15.0, size=1_000)
X = y + np.random.normal(loc=10.0, scale=2.0, size=(y.shape[0], ))
X = X.reshape(-1, 1)

# fit a Poisson regression model
reg = lgb.LGBMRegressor(
    objective="poisson",
    n_estimators=150,
    min_data=1
)
reg.fit(X, y)

# get predictions
preds = reg.predict(X)

print("summary of predicted values")
print(f"  * min: {round(np.min(preds), 3)}")
print(f"  * max: {round(np.max(preds), 3)}")

# compare predicted distribution to the empirical one
bins = np.linspace(0, 30, 50)
pyplot.hist(y, bins, alpha=0.5, label='actual')
pyplot.hist(preds, bins, alpha=0.5, label='predicted')
pyplot.legend(loc='upper right')
pyplot.show()
```

This example uses Python 3.10 and `lightgbm==3.3.3`.

[image]

However... I don't recommend using Poisson regression just to achieve "no negative predictions". The Poisson loss function is intended to be used for cases where you believe your target is Poisson-distributed, e.g. it looks like counts of events observed over some regular interval like time or space.

Other options you might consider to try to achieve the behavior "never predict a negative number from LightGBM regression":

- write a custom objective function in one of the interfaces that support it, like the R or Python package
- post-process LightGBM's predictions, recoding negative values to 0
- pre-process the target variable such that there are no negative values (e.g. dropping such observations, re-scaling, taking the absolute value)